# Unit test for compose HOC

Tags: reactjs, recompose

How can I test this HOC with Enzyme? I've tried shallow but it covers only 40% of component.

```
export default compose(
  withState('showDropdown', 'handleDropdown', false),
  withHandlers({
    handleClickOutside: props => () => {
      props.handleDropdown(false)
    },
    menuItemClick: props => () => {
      props.handleDropdown(false)
    },
  }),
  onClickOutside,
)(AccountDropdown)
```

this is code of my test

```
const props = {
  showDropdown: false,
  handleDropdown: jest.fn(),
  menuItemClick: jest.fn(),
  onLogout: jest.fn(),
  user: {},
}

const output = mount(<AccountDropdown
  showDropdown={props.showDropdown}
  handleDropdown={props.handleDropdown}
  menuItemClick={props.menuItemClick}
  onLogout={props.onLogout}
  user={props.user}
/>)

console.log('output', output)

const TogleDropdown = output.find('TogleDropdown')
console.log('TogleDropdown', TogleDropdown)
expect(shallowToJson(output)).toMatchSnapshot()
```

also i can't test events becouse console.log output:

```
output ReactWrapper {}
```

Comment: have you used `dive()` in your test?

Comment: i tried but it didnt help

Comment: can you add test's code?

Comment: added test's code

Comment: what's `onClickOutside`?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-onclickoutside

Answer (score 0):

Separate your code.
Give the enhancer one file and the component another.

On the enhancer, export only the generated HOC:

```
export default compose(
  withState('showDropdown', 'handleDropdown', false),
  withHandlers({
    handleClickOutside: props => () => {
      props.handleDropdown(false)
    },
    menuItemClick: props => () => {
      props.handleDropdown(false)
    },
  }),
  onClickOutside,
)
```

On the other file, export just the `AccountDropdown` (without wrapping). Then, somewhere else, export the "combination" of them:

```
import enhancer from './enhancer.js';
import AccountDropdown from './AccountDropdown.jsx';

export default enhancer(AccountDropdown);
```

Now, on the tests, import each individual file, "enhance" the component there and find the component properly:

```
import enhancer from './enhancer.js';
import AccountDropdown from './AccountDropdown.jsx';

const Component = enhancer(AccountDropdown);

const props = {
  showDropdown: false,
  handleDropdown: jest.fn(),
  menuItemClick: jest.fn(),
  onLogout: jest.fn(),
  user: {},
}

const output = mount(<Component {...props} />)

const ToggleDropdown = output.find(AccountDropdown) // no quotes
```

your `ToggleDropdown` will have the component for you to test. Example:

```
expect(handleDropdown).to.have.property('callCount', 0);
```

Note that the `mount` will return a `ReactWrapper`, [according to the docs](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/mount.html). You can [take a look at the props](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/props.html) by using the `ToggleDropdown.props()` function.

Comment: i have this error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'isReactComponent' of undefined